# Should I let Skydrive sync my Documents and appdata/roaming folder?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

A lot of applications save their settings either to the documents folder (`/users/<username>/Documents/`) or to appdata (`/users/<username>/appdata/roaming/`) folder. I want my applications to retain the same settings whichever computer I log onto.

Could I damage anything if I set the location of these system-folders (right-click folder and set new location) to the Skydrive folder on both computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do it because as far as I know, SkyDrive can't do merging. If both computers were on at the same time and something was changed in the AppData folder on both - which is likely - SkyDrive would have syncing conflicts.

Comment: What could be the worst case scenario? That i would have to re-apply my updated settings?

Comment: Your settings could be corrupted.